# Bootstrap dropdown still clickable when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a dropdown in my navbar which contains a video player, however when I hide the video player by toggling the dropdown button, I'm still able to click on the hidden div element.

So when I'm trying to navigate other elements on the page, sometimes I click on the hidden div video player. How do I make the hidden div element in droppable unclickable? and then clickable again when I show the element using the dropdown.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using the following code:

```
<a ng-cloak class="dropdown-toggle player-btn btn btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown">TOGGLE</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div style='position:relative;height:210px'>
              <div style='position:relative;height:210px'>
                  <div id="player"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful for us to know how you hide/show

Comment: post the js code use for toggle/show-hide u have written inorder to help..

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your issue? make sure to include any plugins you're using

Comment: there's no javascript code just twitter bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Were you using IE 10 at the time ?